# using betareg in coding with R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and I am supposed to make a model thanks to regression beta. I learned that I can use `betareg()` except that even when installing its package the R does not recognize it and displays me error:

> Error: could not find function "betareg"

What could be the cause for that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question does not supply enough information, please take a look a the help on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you are getting typically arises when calling a function.
Before you can call a function, you have to install the package and load the library.

You can try this:

```
install.packages("betareg")
library(betareg)
```

and then call the function with relevant parameters

```
betareg()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm going to ask you another question. the dependent variable admits even the 0 and1 and by using the betareg () function I get this error:  Error in if (!(min(Y) > 0 & max(Y) < 1)) stop("invalid dependent variable, all observations must be in (0, 1)") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In model.response(mf, "numeric") : NAs introduced by coercion  Knowing that I use as link the function probit, or logit or clog-log but it does not work. I do not know if it is due to the package or the handling with which I write the arguments of betareg.

Comment: @E.Marwa it'll be easier for us to help you if you post a separate question. please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guide and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) guide for help with formulating the question in order to maximize chances of getting an answer. :)